I am converting pdf to excel using aspose.pdf in python . But issue is that it is only converting starting 4 pages of pdf to excel. Below is my code
from tkinter import *
import aspose.pdf as ap
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd

input_pdf = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("PDF Files", "*.pdf"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
 output_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx",
                                      `your text`filetypes=(("Excel Files", "*.xlsx"), ("All Files","*.*")))

    document = ap.Document(input_pdf)


    save_option = ap.ExcelSaveOptions()
    save_option.minimize_the_number_of_worksheets = True
    print("Page Count:", str(len(document.pages)))
    save_option.Number= (0, len(document.pages))  

    document.save(output_file, save_option)

`

Please don't treat the title of the question as the entire question. The title should summarize your question, but in the body of the question, you should provide more details about your problem, the expected results and actual results (see also [mre]). Please [edit] your question to improve it.
